# "does not name a type" simple program Error

Tags: c++

What's the problem here? 
Why there is an error ? Im a beginner :P

```
#include <iostream>

int var = 3;
int *Pointer;
Pointer = &var; // Error here: "Pointer does not name a type"

int main ()
{

  std::cout << Pointer;  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Pointer = &var;
```

This is a statement that performs an action (rather than declaring a thing).

You can't have it floating about in random space. It must be in a function, so that your computer knows *when* to execute it.

Either:

- move that assignment statement into `main`, or
- replace it, and the previous line, with an *initialisation* so that it may be part of the initial declaration:

  ```
  int* Pointer = &val;
  ```